# Designing CFG that accepts $b^m a^n$ ($m ≤ n$)

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I am trying to design a CFG that generates the language $\{a^k b^m a^n a^k \mid m \leq n\}$. However, I am having trouble with the $b^m a^n$ where $m \leq n$. How do I solve this?

Comment: Think of it as $b^m a^m a^k$ where $k = n-m \ge 0$

Comment: So you know you'll have to generate $P\to bPa$, except sometimes the $b$ might be missing...

Answer (score 1):

You can write this language as
$$
\{ a^k b^m a^m a^\ell a^k \mid k,m,\ell \in \mathbb{N} \}.
$$
This description easily lends itself to conversion into a context-free grammar.